# Number theory Legendre problem please

Tags: number-theory

How to solve Legendre symbol. $\left(\frac{-2}{59}\right)$

I know that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$
Can anyone briefly tell me how to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since $59$ is of the shape $4k+3$, we have $\left(\frac{-1}{59}\right)=-1$.

Since $59$ is of the shape $8k\pm 3$, we have $\left(\frac{2}{59}\right)=-1$.

Thus $\left(\frac{-2}{59}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{59}\right)\left(\frac{2}{59}\right)=1$.